# Preferential Sorting for Lists on Merge

Tags: c#, generics, sorting

I have two lists of the same type of object.

One list comes from the system administrators, and the other comes from the user viewing the page.

These lists must be merged for viewing at some point and it is likely that the value `position` which the lists are sorted on will have conflicting values.

Is there a way to merge the two lists, and when identical values are found for position, to give the lower (and therefore better) spot to the admin list?

EXAMPLE

```
class info
{
  int position;
  string title;
}

List<info> adminInfo = new List<info> 
{
  new info() {position = 0, title = "adminOne"}
  new info() {position = 4, title = "adminThree"}
  new info() {position = 3, title = "adminTwo"}
}

List<info> userInfo = new List<info> 
{
  new info() {position = 0, title = "userOne"}
  new info() {position = 3, title = "userTwo"}
}

List<info> PreferentiallySortedList(List<info> adminList, List<info> userList)
{
  //Some kind of magic here
}

//Looping through PreferentiallySortedList and displaying 
//the title of each item should return the following:

"adminOne"
"userOne"
"adminTwo"
"userTwo"
"adminThree"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (code-wise) is to use LINQ with a Union and create a new anonymous class that contains a priority and the `info`.

Something like this (may have syntax errors)

```
return adminList
   .Select(info => new {Priority = 0, Info = info})
   .Union(userList.Select(info => new {Priority = 1, Info = info}))
   .SortBy(u => u.Info.position)
   .ThenBy(u => u.Priority)
   .Select(u => u.Info)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: I see, so I need to add a second flag to my class, mark all admin objects as 0, then all user objects as 1, and if I do an orderby position, thenby priority it should order correctly.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct.  But I am using an anonymous to do the sorting so you do *NOT* have to modify the existing info class.  Paste my code into `some kind of magic` and everything should be sweet.

Comment: BTW, C# convention is to upper camel case class, method and property names, so `class info` should be `class Info`.

Comment: @RichardSchneider `.SortBy(u => u.Info.position)` probably `OrderBy'?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov thanks.  I'm on smartphone and have to do everything from memory, which has been failing for last 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

If each `info` occurs only in one of the lists, you may do it not using anonymous objects. Union lists, order by `position`, then by whether an element is contained in `adminList`:

```
List<info> PreferentiallySortedList(List<info> adminList, List<info> userList)
{
    return adminList.Union(userList)
                    .OrderBy(u => u.position)
                    .ThenBy(u => !adminList.Contains(u))
                    .ToList();
}
```

Depending on the size of the lists, performance considerations may be necessary.

Comment: This would not order admin before user info when positions are the same.

Comment: Given the above example, yes the titles are alphabetical and that would work. I do not believe this continues to work if that is not the case.

Comment: Would this not give a wrong order if the user list had title as "ABC" and the admin list had title as "DEF" for the same value of position ?